# ASP.NET Form inside a Hidden Div won't work

Tags: asp.net

I have a login FORM inside a Hidden DIV, this DIV is hidden using CSS `display:none;` when I click on some other DIV, I show this DIV using jquery `.slideDown()`, so I can be able to use this form.

When I click on the button, the `OnClick="Login"` doesn't seem to work,and when I removed this form from this hidden div to simply another place in the body, it worked. What's the problem?

**ASP.NET:**

```
<div id="userCPContainer">
<form id="loginForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username" class="loginLabels"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="usernameField" runat="server" MaxLength="50" class="loginFields"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password" class="loginLabels"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="passwordField" runat="server" MaxLength="50" 
        TextMode="Password" class="loginFields"></asp:TextBox>


    <asp:Button ID="loginButton" runat="server" Text="Log in" onclick="Loginn" class="loginButton"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
function showUserCP() {

    $("#userCPContainer").slideDown(200);
    $(".userCPDiv").css("background-color", "#000000");
    $(".userCPDiv").css("border-color", "#000000");
}

function hideUserCP() {
    $(".userCPDiv").css("background-color", "rgb(43, 147, 206)");
    $(".userCPDiv").css("border-color", "rgb(43, 147, 206)");
    $("#userCPContainer").slideUp(200);

}

$(".userCPDiv").click(function (e) {
        //Either way, hide Main Menu
        hideMainMenu();
        if ($("#userCPContainer").is(":visible")) {
            hideUserCP();
        }
        else {
            showUserCP();
        }
        e.stopPropagation();

    });
```

**CSS:**

```
#userCPContainer
{
    overflow:hidden;
    border-style:solid;
    border-top-style:none;
    border-color:rgb(43,147,206);
    border-width:2px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    width:300px;
    background-color:  #000000;
}
```

Nothing really complicated...

Comment: Does your main page already have the form tags on it? If so, get rid of the form tags in the code above - you don't need them.

Comment: where is the `userCPDiv` div ? Maybe this overlap the button, accept all the clicks and not allow them to hit the button.

Comment: Sorry guys it's my bad, the login box will slide down, so I had some jquery codes that tells the site that whenever I click on any place in the document, this login box should slide Up, so I wrote other codes which says that whenever I click on #userCPContainer... return false.. I removed it, it worked by now I sacrificed the "hide on click", need to find another way. thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use CSS `display: none;` the problem is that all that's inside that DIV gets removed completely from the HTML Document and that causes that ASP.NET does not recognize this element when you show it via jQuery. I see to possible solutions:

1. Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none;`, if you do this you will probably have some problems with the DIV height because it will take the space needed to render but it will not be visible.
2. Use a `ScriptManager` and an `UpdatePanel` and put the div and the form inside those elements, so the server will know when you render the Button in the client. Also, make sure that you register your jQuery scripts inside the `ScriptManager`

Hope this helps you